# How to get List of providerType based on Database Type while creating a JDBC provider using jython in IBM WebSphere Application Server?

Tags: websphere, jython

I used the below Command to get List of providerType value based on DatabaseType to create JDBC Provider

`wsadmin>print AdminTask.listIdMgrSupportedDBTypes()`
It got the list of Database type as
db2, oracle, informix, sqlserver, derby, db2zos, db2iseries

I need to list the ProviderType based on Above DatabaseTypes value like "db2"

Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following command will list the available JDBC provider types:

```
print AdminConfig.listTemplates('JDBCProvider')
```

You can further filter with an additional parameter, which you would need to map from your list of returned values because the databaseType values don't match exactly,

```
wsadmin>print AdminConfig.listTemplates('JDBCProvider', 'Informix')
```

AdminConfig.showAttribute can be used on any of the resulting values to get the providerType. (You might wish to filter on other attributes as well)

```
wsadmin>print AdminConfig.showAttribute("Informix Using IBM JCC Driver(templates/system|jdbc-resource-provider-templates.xml#JDBCProvider_Informix_JCC4_1)", 'providerType')
Informix Using IBM JCC Driver
```

which you can supply along with the database type as an argument to [AdminTask.createJDBCProvider](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/rxml_atjdbcprovider.html?view=kc#rxml_atjdbcprovider__cmd3)

```
AdminTask.createJDBCProvider('[-scope Node=myNode,Server=server1 -databaseType informix -providerType "Informix Using IBM JCC Driver" -implementationType "XA data source" -name "Informix test 1" ]')
```

Comment: I need list dynamically all those available provider types based database types to automate jdbc provider configuration

Comment: Are you attempting to do this in the context of using VMM?  The original AdminTask command you've listed is specific to the id manager functionality of WebSphere Application Server.

Comment: Oh k. what is the alternative command to list database available in the websphere application server. I need all those values which are in select option should list dynamically. can you help?

Comment: I don't know that there is any way to programmatically list the configurable database types available.  Is there a reason this needs to be done dynamically vs relying on a static list, such as is documented on this page for databaseType?

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rxml_7adminjdbc.html#rxml_7adminjdbc__scr10

"Specifies the database type that this JDBC provider uses. Valid values include DB2, Derby, Informix, Oracle, Sybase, SQL Server, and user-defined values."